# Epic's App Orchard Oauth server to server flow

Tags: oauth, hl7-fhir

Have anyone had any luck implementing Epic's App Orchard Oauth flow (server to server flow. no user interaction)

I'm trying to get OAuth flow working from the point a user launches our app from Epic's patient chart. The user would trigger a request to our app with a launch token. From there we'd use this token to get access_token and then query a few APIs.

The issue is that there is very little documentation. The steps I was able to piece together fail when requesting /oauth2/token endpoint. The only error indication is in body json containing this:

```
{"error":"invalid_request"}
```

No other errors or indications for failure points. So I'm looking for anyone who had any luck with such authentication to Epic's FHIR APIs.

My request query params look like this:

```
serverBaseURl +
            "/oauth2/token?" +
            "grant_type=authorization_code" +
            "&client_id=" + clientId +
            "&code=" + encodeURI(code) + //<-- code from /oauth2/authorize step
            "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURI(redirectUrl) //<-- url declared in app configuration
```

I know this isn't super clear question, but if anyone has any pointers , it's really appreciated

Comment: How do you get authorization code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oauth2/token endpoint accepts a url-encoded form as the POST body instead of query parameters.